# UDP reverse proxy

Tags: networking, port-forwarding, udp

Is there any easy way of doing userspace UDP reverse proxying?

Specifically, I want the equivalent of

```
ssh -R 10000:localhost:10000 $server
```

but for UDP.

I want this approach to be *unreliable* in the sense that if a packet gets lost between me and the server no retransmit occurs.
Also assume the client machine is unable to *receive* UDP packets.

## Research / approaches considered

- Openvpn does this tunnelling at the IP level. It feels like of heavy weight in terms of configuration, requires quite a lot of settings
- `socat` might be able to magically do this. But I couldn't find a way from looking at the docs
- There is something called a "VPN TAP" interface which sounds kind of like a virtual wire between you and a server. I found some open source programs that claimed to create a user space TAP interface
- [This page](http://zarb.org/~gc/html/udp-in-ssh-tunneling.html) discusses routing UDP over TCP (note that this creates retransmission)
- [frp](https://github.com/fatedier/frp#forward-unix-domain-socket) looks potentially easy - but I can't tell what it does from an initial inspection.

## Openvpn

As people have made clear in the comments in terms of raw performance OpenVPN is the best approach (as it is for TCP packet forwarding for that matter - assuming encryption is required). Of course the downside is this requires root processes on both sides of the connection, certificates, configuration files, a couple of IP addresses and some routing rules for these IP addresses.

Comment: Openvpn is super easy to [configure](https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/miscellaneous/78-static-key-mini-howto.html) and as lightweight as it can. About +30 bytes / packet.

Comment: **Openvpn** Hmm, Root + kernel components + certificates + IP address + the potential for ip address collisions feel like a bit of a pain when compared to ssh tunnelling if you just want to say "take these UDP packets here and feed them into this port on localhost"

Comment: **>  But if you know everything better than me, then please don't ask anything!**
 A bit offensive there don't you think? Umm, I don't really know if I know more than you. I probably know more about my intended use case :P. Though I imagine you might know more about openvpn as I haven't set up openvpn for a couple of years and then it was a pain. I'm quite sure you are correct that openvpn is more *performant* than ssh tunnels. I'm more interested in something that I can use for hacky one off tasks in a similar way to ssh... in there's a way to use openvpn like `ssh -R` that'd be awesome!

Comment: If you know more about the intended use case, please edit the question and add the information - it's difficult for us to guess (OpenVPN does UDP as required, and does have less overhead, and does create a tun/tap interface), it makes it harder for us to answer the question, and without it, it can easily become an [XY-Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: **If you know more about the intended use case, please** I feel the question is clear as it stands. **it's difficult for us** Who is us? I guess it's a rhetorical majority excluding me right? **it can easily become an XY-Problem.** boring, everything is an X-Y problem. Do you want my whole live history as well? Let me offer you an alternative explanation: people don't know how to answer the question so they insist on saying "X-Y Problem!" in the hope that they might get to something they know.  I think your comment adds nothing and amounts to little more than cliched back-patting.

Comment: As previously stated, in the comments and in the original question. **does have less overhead** What are you contradicting with that does? It has considerably more *configuration* overhead than an ssh tunnel (two certificates, two ip addresses, a root process, two routing rules, two configuration files) as made clear in the original question: "It feels like of heavy weight in terms of configuration, requires quite a lot of settings". Look I already know about openvpn, and know what it is one approach that's why I included in the original question and said *userspace* and less configuration.

Answer (score 1):

You could place a SOCKS proxy on the other end of the SSH tunnel. *If I remember correctly*, one of the example scripts that comes with `libio-socket-socks-perl` should be enough after a tiny tweak of parameters.

Comment: What would this do in the case of packet loss? If possible I'd like to preserve the "unreliability" of UDP :).

Comment: @AttRigh In UDP packet loss is packet loss, as far as I know. The tunnel only cares about the TCP layer. All the rest is UDP, so unreliable by definition.

Comment: Hmm. So the thing is that if a packet gets lost *between* me and the server then that packet must be resent before any latter packets arrive... if I'm correct. So one dropped UDP packet delays all other UDP packets by a couple of round trip times (the use case I have in mind is things like streaming audio and video behind rubbish third party wifi). Although... maybe I should be using an openvpn at all times anyway - I clearly don't value my privacy or security (!)

Comment: @AttRigh There are two layers here. TCP beneath and UDP on top of it. They don't know about each other. TCP is reliable, so in case something doesn't arrive, then it resends. If you want to have a really crap-wifi-"proof" transmission system, then you should think of a double-UDP one. OpenVPN should do exactly this, as it will be double-UDP. But if you mean TCP on top of UDP, then I'm affraid OpenVPN won't provide you with what you want. TCP requires reliability. But for streaming videos it should be ok (I guess, 99% certainty). As for the delays, I don't think relays are that stupid...

Comment: @AttRigh ...to wait with the transmission of what's there in the buffer for a single lost packets. In fact, it's a known thing that packets will often arrived in an unsorted sequence. But they need to arrive, otherwise a resend request will be issued.

Comment: Thanks for the details. **"then you should think of a double-UDP on"** Indeed. The issue is that because UDP is "connectionless* you need to be able to accept in bound UDP packets from the client for this to work reliably. I kind of want UDP "with a connection".  It should be noted that there are some protocols for allowing inbound UDP connections behind a NATing router.. it's just that they don't always work. I guess openvpn might be all there is (easily) (other than over TCP).  I had hoped their might be some obscure "unreliable ppp/ip" protocol.

Comment: @AttRigh I don't know what you mean by accepting inbound UDP packets from the client. If there's a service with UDP nothing has to be accepted, it works the same as TCP. I can't think of any other protocols. But then, I'm not very knowledgable. Other people might help you, but you should specify what you want in your question, as you seem not to be crystal clear about it. Also if you reply to other people address them by tag, as they won't even know you do. (See the beginning of this comment.)

Answer (score 0):

the tools that i noticed work to reverse proxy UDP are:

- frp, like you mentioned, i tested it (they have a dns example)
- nginx with stream directive and listen udp:

  stream {

  server {
  listen     10000 udp;
  proxy_pass backend:10000;
  }

}
(as you see, the first one reverse-proxies UDP, it will also proxy back all the responses, because in DNS responses can be multiple, like a whole video & audio stream from peers)

- I think https://github.com/snail007/goproxy may work too